# My Bot::BasicBot based Perl bot only connects but does not perform other actions

Tags: perl, bots, chatbot, irc

I am trying to make a perl bot connecting to IRC with the Bot::BasicBot package but even the most simple subroutines don't seem to have effect on the bot's behaviour. I am a beginner in Perl programming and I have probably forgotten some very obvious stuff but I have not been able to find that online.
Here is my code :

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Bot::BasicBot;
package main;
use base qw( Bot::BasicBot );

my $bot = Bot::BasicBot->new(
server    =>    "server",
port      => '6667',
channels  => ['#channel'],
nick      => 'Bot',
name      => 'Bot',
)->run();

sub help {"I kinda work"};
sub connected {
  print "I am connected !";
}
```

The bot correctly connects to the the server and channel I specify (at least I can see the bot in the list of users connected) but saying help to the bot returns "Sorry, this bot has no interactive help."
The *connected* subroutine does not work either or at least does not output the message on standard output. I don't know how to make this work - there is few documentation online, and I'd appreciate some help from you guys please.

Comment: From the documentation of the module I get the impression that you need to redefine the `help` and `connected` subroutines of the package of the bot. Which means that you should either subclass `Bot::BasicBot`, or add `package Bot::BasicBot` before defining the subs `help` and `connected`. The former is better for a full program, but the later is fine for testing (and if you do the later, you might want to add `no warnings 'redefine'`).